# error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods- hand writing coding using notepad

Tags: c#

Getting the error on line 16, with the foreach. My professor wont email fast enough and the due date is in a few hours! I think I am missing a list or something. I think the d after the double is incorrect. Any help is appectiated!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Starbucks
{
 public static void Main()
{
 double[] x = {4.2, 5.7, 3.6, 9.1, 2.7, 8.4 };
 }
}

static void MyGenerics(double x)
{
 foreach (double d in x)
 {
  MessageBox.Show(x);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have defined the `MyGenerics()` method outside the class `Starbucks`. Move it inside the class. Error message is exactly telling the same thing. Your code should look like

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Starbucks
{
 public static void Main()
{
  double[] x = {4.2, 5.7, 3.6, 9.1, 2.7, 8.4 };
  MyGenerics(x);
 }

static void MyGenerics(double[] xx)
{
 foreach (double d in xx)
 {
  MessageBox.Show(d);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the only topic in class that was confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by bad indentation. For example:

```
using System;

namespace Interrogacion_1.Model
{
    interface IClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD"); #here error cs0116
    }
}
```

The correct way would be:

```
using System;

namespace Interrogacion_1.Model
{
    interface IClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public void Imprimir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com generally [works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/);